# Analytics API returning 0 for Returning User/Visitor yet interface shows number

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using the following query, which I have been using monthly with no problem so far to query for user data for a given profile for the last month.

```
  ids: ga:********
  start-date: 2020-05-01,
  end-date: 2020-05-31,
  metric: ga:users,
  dimensions: ga:userType,
```

How ever this month its returns 0 for returning users:

```
New Visitor:        81,026
Returning Visitor:  0
```

Yet in the interface I can see the numbers with the same parameters:

[image: Google Analytics Interface 1]

[image: Google Analytics Interface 2]

Any help or insight appreciated

Comment: is the interface also checking on ga:userType?  You cant compare to unrelated reports.  The dimensions and metrics used in the API must be exactly the same as the Dimensions and metrics you are looking at in the Interface.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but are those the correct dimensions in the second screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

As it appears that `ga:userType` dimension has become bugged within the last month.

I fixed this issue by breaking the query in to two as follows:

```
      tableId,
      2020-05-01,
      2020-05-31,
      'ga:users',
      segment: 'sessions::condition::ga:userType==New Visitor',
```

```
      tableId,
      2020-05-01,
      2020-05-31,
      'ga:users',
      segment: 'sessions::condition::ga:userType==Returning Visitor',
```